# ActionScript 3 - Remove video from stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a video i am playing on the stage, once the video has stopped playing I either want the video to be removed or to go to a new frame.

I have tried using playheadTime to do this but it doesn't work.

Here is the code i've tried

```
if(badVideo.playheadTime == 115)
    {
    stage.removeChild(badVideo  );
    }
```

The video is 1:55 long

If any one knows how I should go about doing this it would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you use FLVPlayback...

You need to use the COMPLETE event :

```
import fl.video.VideoEvent;

badVideo.addEventListener( VideoEvent.COMPLETE , onVideoComplete);

function onVideoComplete(e:VideoEvent):void {
  badVideo.removeEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE , onVideoComplete);
 // do what you want
}
```

[Doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_fr/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event%3acomplete)

Comment: For jump on to requested frame replace '// do what you want' with 'badVideo.seek(TIME);'; doc: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002450.html

Comment: To remove video replace '// do what you want' with 'badVideo.parent.removeChild(badVideo);'

Comment: Thanks RafH worked great, only slight change I had to make was to add a direct path to the COMPLETE event as flash cs6 didn't seem to be picking it up. badVideo.addEventListener( fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE , onVideoComplete);